# Pivot with Label Column (U-SQL or SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot, u-sql

I'm trying to pivot a list of columns into rows in a single column (which I will call 'forecast'), but with an indicator column noting which column that value came from.

Here is how the data currently looks:

[image]

And here is how I want it to look:

[image]

Comment: Please add data as formatted text **not** images. It takes up less space, is easier to read, and most importantly allows us to copy and paste it out for testing. Ideally provide DDL/DML to create the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join to unpivot the columns to rows, while keeping track of the original column:

```
select t.productID, x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    (period1, 1), (period2, 2), (period3, 3)
) as x(forecast, periodNum)
order by t.productID, x.periodNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out by using UNPIVOT! (FYI Using Cross Apply in U-SQL is more complex than in vanilla SQL, so I didn't wind up using that approach)

My syntax in U-SQL looks like this:

```
@a = SELECT DISTINCT
ProductID
,Lag
,Forecast
FROM [my table] AS t
UNPIVOT
(
Forecast FOR Lag IN (PERIOD1,PERIOD2,PERIOD3)
) AS Unpvt
ORDER BY ColumnName
FETCH 50 ROWS;


OUTPUT @a
TO "/outputlocation.tsv"
USING Outputters.Tsv(outputHeader:true);
```